# Black screen after sleep on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, display

I have recently acquired a new laptop (msi leopard pro gp62 6qe, with Windows 10 installed) but there is an issue that I don't how to fix.

Whenever I try to turn it on after it sleeps (when I close the lid for example), the screen remains absolutely black, no matter how long I wait or how many keys I press. Therefore, I can hear sounds (the computer waiting for my password, and if I press enter with something wrong there is the sound notification) so I presume that my laptop is running well except for the display.

I have updated the drivers, and tried to change some of the sleep presets, but nothing seems to work.

It has always happened, since the first time I have closed the lid and reopened it. I can't really tell what I have installed before that, but nothing unusual (Chrome, Avast, Steam, etc.). I have not connected it to anything external neither. I am wondering if it's a BIOS issue.

Would anyone have an idea on how to fix this issue?

Comment: did you revert all of your power settings to the defaults? advanced power settings included?

Comment: I've had this in relation to a connection to an external monitor. Do you have any connections to anything that the system might be treating as an external display (inc. wireless connections to tablets, etc.)?

It's a bit difficult without a bit more information on whether this has always happened since it was taken out of the box, or if you had just installed a new piece of software/hardware.

Comment: @ErdemEce Yes I have tried that, it doesn't fix the issue sadly.

Comment: @RichardAllan It has always happened, since the first time I have closed the lid and reopened it. I can't really tell what I have installed before that, but nothing unusal (Chrome, Avast, Steam, etc.). I have not connected it to anything external neither. I wonder if it's a BIOS issue ?

Comment: Check the MSI website for any BIOS or driver updates. Install all Windows updates as well. If that doesn't resolve this, and this is a new laptop under warranty, you should contact the manufacturer.

Comment: It could be informative to connect using the network when it has a dark screen (such as teamviewer).   If your screen stays black but you can connect via the network, you can see if any settings have changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated the BIOS of my laptop, and now it seems to work well.

Here is a useful link if anyone has the same problem on a msi laptop in the future: https://www.msi.com/files/pdf/Flash_BIOS_by_UEFI_BIOS_Setup_Utility_en.pdf.

Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: @RichardAllan Thanks for your help, only on my laptop model it's not easy at all to remove the battery...Which is why I tried to update the BIOS first.

Comment: Not a problem! Sorry - I will admit I didn't research your specific model before suggesting this.

Answer (score 0):

OK - Given what you have described, one option will be to complete a hard reset - that is:

- Turn off the Laptop
- Eject the battery from the machine
- Wait a few seconds and return the battery to the machine
- Hold Shift+F8 while turning the laptop on again for the first time
- Hopefully, celebrate when your laptop doesn't do this again

When I've been helping people with issues related to the Login Screen with Laptops, I've found that this sequence will help resolve it.

Comment: To back up your claim, do you have any reference to this being how to reset this laptop?

Comment: @CharlieRB - Mostly through personal experience - I have found hard resets like this has sorted a variety of issues related to login screens. In terms of specifics - Shift + F8 is one of the safe mode login methods for Windows 10. [link](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/4-ways-boot-safe-mode-windows-10)

Comment: You should [edit] this info into your answer. Personal experience is great and adds validity to what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

My friend had the same problem (with different laptop, I think). The quick and dirty solution was to change the brightness (by <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F-something</kbd>) when it happened – and the screen lit up every time.

Comment: that didn't work for me though...

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar problem after fresh install of Windows 10 (*Creators Update*) on my Toshiba laptop.

Solution that worked for me was to upgrade *Intel(R) Management Engine Interface* (MEI) driver to the most recent version. This update wasn't available in Windows Update, I used DriverMax to find one.

This particular driver was [mentioned in similar threads](http://www.lostwindowspassword.com/windows-10/windows-10-will-not-wake-up-from-sleep-mode.html) in the past, so it might be worth to give it a shot.

I remember having this problem in the past on the same machine and driver update solved it too.